# Meteor & noUiSlider: how can I listen to events?

Tags: javascript, meteor, nouislider

I just got the noUiSlider for meteor, but am having problems with listening to events. Here is my code:

```
Template.templateOne.events({
  'click #slider': function(){
    console.log('event works!');
  }
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. According to [this](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/) there is also build in events such as slide. How can I use them in Meteor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it mandatory to bind it like this...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it mandatory to bind it like this...??

```
Template.templateOne.events({
  'click #slider': function(){
    console.log('event works!');
  }
});
```

i think you can do it like this:

```
 var noui = document.getElementById('#slider');
 noui.noUiSlider.on('slide', function(){
    console.log('i think it will work');
 });
```

ok then do it like this

```
Template.templateOne.rendered = function () {
    var slider = document.getElementById('#slider')
    this.slider.noUiSlider({
      start: Session.get("slider"),
      connect: true,
      range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
      }
    }).on('slide', function (ev, val) {

      console.log('i think it will work');

      Session.set('slider', val);
    }).on('change', function (ev, val) {
      // round off values on 'change' event
      Session.set('slider', [Math.round(val[0]), Math.round(val[1])]);
    });
  };
```

you can look on this example https://github.com/rcy/meteor-nouislider/blob/master/example/example.js

Comment: I don't quiet understand. should I just copy this code into the js file? I had the impression that in Meteor everything needs to be in events or helpers